# Is it OK to use \tt etc. in latex2e if you don't want the text to inherit the font of the containing text?

Tags: fonts, formatting, best-practices, obsolete

I want some words to always be in upright teletype (they are defined to be something specific). 
If the sentence is emphasised and this word appears I do not want the text to be italic teletype, but remain upright teletype. 
In this case is it OK to use {\tt word} to achieve this effect or is there some better way?

```
\emph{A sentence that contains the {\tt word} yet it remains upright teletype.}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\tt` is obsolete with LaTeX2e, it's just defined by classes. So, if you use a class that's still supporting it, it would work. But I would not recommend it.
Classes like `article.cls` define for compatibility:

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
```

I would use `\normalfont\ttfamily`. Further, I wouldn't use it in the body text but in the preamble, defining a logical markup like `\code`.